# Showing the current user's tasks in a Content Editor Web Part using JQuery

Tags: jquery, content-editor-web-part, caml-query

I have been searching this site for an answer but I have been unable to find anything that will work.

I have been trouble pulling the tasks of the current user from a subsite. I am using SharePoint 2007 and I want to be able to display tasks that are assigned to the logged in user and has not been completed yet. I suspect something is wrong with CAML. When the query is not included, the CEWP displays all the tasks in the task list.

```
var soapEnv =
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
        <soapenv:Body> \
            <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                <listName>Tasks</listName> \
                <viewFields> \
                    <ViewFields> \
                        <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                        <FieldRef Name='ID' /> \
                    </ViewFields> \
                </viewFields> \
                <query> \
                    <Query> \
                        <Where> \
                            <And> \
                                <Eq> \
                                    <FieldRef Name=’AssignedTo’></FieldRef> \
                                    <Value Type=’Integer’><UserID Type=’Integer’ /></Value> \
                                </Eq> \
                                <Neq> \
                                    <FieldRef Name=’Status’/> \
                                    <Value Type=’Text’>Completed</Value> \ 
                                </Neq> \
                            </And> \
                        </Where> \
                  </Query> \
                </query> \
            </GetListItems> \
        </soapenv:Body> \
    </soapenv:Envelope>";
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what ended up finally working:

```
var soapEnv =
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
        <soapenv:Body> \
            <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                <listName>Tasks</listName> \
                <query> \
                    <Query> \
                        <Where> \
                            <And> \
                                <Eq> \
                                    <FieldRef Name='AssignedTo'></FieldRef> \
                                    <Value Type='Integer'><UserID Type='Integer' /></Value> \
                                </Eq> \
                                <Neq> \
                                    <FieldRef Name='Status'></FieldRef> \
                                    <Value Type='Choice'>Completed</Value> \
                                </Neq> \
                            </And> \
                        </Where> \
                    </Query> \
                </query> \
                <viewFields> \
                    <ViewFields> \
                        <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                        <FieldRef Name='ID' /> \
                    </ViewFields> \
                </viewFields> \
            </GetListItems> \
        </soapenv:Body> \
    </soapenv:Envelope>";
```

I fooled around with the CAML and it finally worked.

Comment: How to implement this in Content Editor WebPart.

Answer (score 2):

I second James' suggestion to use [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com), but I wrote it, so I'm not to be trusted.

It looks like you might have "smart quotes" in your query:

`<FieldRef Name=’AssignedTo’`>

Make sure those are "straight quotes" instead.

Comment: The quotes are correct in the query. They showed up as the curved quotes when I copy pasted it into here.

Comment: I'd delete the quotes and re-add them, just to be doubly (lol, pun) sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have 'query' nested inside a 'Query' block. Only use the Query with the upper case, and remove the one in lower case.

Comment: i removed the <query> and </query> and it did not work. I thought you needed to lower case <query> to signify the query portion of the envelope and the <Query> to signify the actual query

Comment: There's something similar with the viewFields portion, too. Direct injection of SOAP envelopes is a pretty unstable way of accessing the web services, have you tried using SPServices? This greatly reduces the complexity of simple tasks like querying lists. http://spservices.codeplex.com/